# System.Numerics.Vectors and Windows 7 - does not work

Tags: c#, vector

The version of System.Numerics.Vectors in the package manager is incomplete and really needs an update. In particular, setting the position of a matrix fails on a "Matrix.Invert() method not found".

The version of System.Numerics.Vectors in the coreFX Github download does not work with Windows 7.

Using Visual Studio 2013.

How do I get a version of System.Numerics.Vectors which works?

Answer (score 0):

The [Nuget page](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/4.1.0-beta-23019) for System.Numerics.Vectors 4.1.0-beta-23019 has a Contact Owners link that might get you an answer.

However older versions of the package (like [this one](http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/1.1.6-beta)) include a Supported Targets list:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8
- Portable Class Libraries

It's possible the answer you get will be "not supported".  On the other hand the new page doesn't have a Supported Targets list so perhaps the new beta is more widely supported?